# WordPress: Use <picture>-tag with wp_get_attachment_image

Tags: php, html, wordpress, responsive-design, responsive-images

I want to use the `<picure>`-tag with the function `wp_get_attachment_image`.
At the moment I'm getting an `<img>`-tag with `srcset`. That's nice but is there any way to change it to a `<picure>`-tag with multiple sources in it? Like this:

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 56.25em)" srcset="large.jpg 1x, large@2x.jpg 2x">
  <source media="(min-width: 37.5em)" srcset="medium.jpg 1x, medium@2x.jpg 2x">
  <source srcset="small.jpg 1x, small@2x.jpg 2x">
  <img src="fallback.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

I need that because I want to display a second version of the image. So I can have horizontal and vertical images in one `<picture>`-tag. Like this:

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 38em)" srcset="art-direction-horizontal.jpg">
  <source srcset="art-direction-vertical.jpg">
  <img src="art-direction-vertical.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

Comment: There isn't a way to modify the output of `wp_get_attachment_image`; you'd need to come up with a function yourself. You could use the existing [function definition](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.3/src/wp-includes/media.php#L983) to help you though.

Comment: You might be able to do that using [APD](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apd.php)'s [override_function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) from an init hook (`add_action('init', 'override_wp_get_attachment_image')`). But seeing as this is a debugging component, you may not want to run this extension in a production environment. Another (hacky) way might be to patch `wp-includes/media.php`. But again, possibly not something you want to do on prod. Then again, WP doesn't leave you any clean options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 5.6.0, We get a way to wrap img elements.

```
apply_filters( 'wp_get_attachment_image', $html, $attachment_id, $size, $icon, $attr );
```

The filter does not extract post_id but attachment_id. So if you want to activate the function systematically, You should link an attachment and its mobile image via post meta.

```
function wrap_wp_get_attachment_image_with_picture_tag( $html, $attachment_id, $size, $icon, $attr ){
    if ( is_admin() || $size == 'medium' || $size == 'thumbnail' ) return $html;
    if ( $mobile_id = get_post_meta( $attachment_id, '_meta_key_of_mobile_picuture_id', true ) ){
        $mobile_srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $mobile_id, 'medium_large' );
        $html = '<picture><source media="( max-width : 782px )" srcset="'.$mobile_srcset.'">'.$html.'</picture>';
    }
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image', 'wrap_wp_get_attachment_image_with_picture_tag', 10, 5 );
```